# Divisibleby not working in django template

Tags: python, django, templates

I want to create a site gallery in django, where each line contains two pictures and there will be two columns. I have a code like this, but the pictures appear one after another.

```
{% block content %}
    <ul>
            <li>
                {% for image in gallery %}
                    {{ image.title }} <br>
                    <img src="{{ image.paint.url }}" width="300px"><br>
                    {{ image.status }}<br>
                    {{ image.price }}<br>

                    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"2" %}
                        </li>
                        <li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </li>
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Maybe you better use a table instead an unordered list.

Comment: do you get the html structure that you expected or not?  the problem could be in your css

Comment: @Anentropic Resultat is not what I expected.

Comment: what result do you get?